# zip extractor reading archives from stdin

Tags: linux, command-line, cygwin, zip, stdin

As follows from `UNZIP(1L)` man page

> Archives read from standard input are not yet supported

Are there another CLI programs running under Linux/cygwin which can extract from zip archives reading them from stdin?

Comment: Hmm 7z was the first thing came to my mind but it's a no-go... `7z x -si < sample.zip` returns `Error: E_NOTIMPL` and documentation confirms that reading zip files from stdin is not yet supported.

Comment: `cat archive.zip | tar -xvf -` works on BSD/OS X, but not with gnu tar.

Comment: see also [How to unzip a piped zip file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7132514/how-to-unzip-a-piped-zip-file-from-wget-qo) -- tldr: use `bsdtar`

Answer (score 7):

Repost of [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52759718/9645167):

BusyBox's `unzip` can take stdin and extract all the files.

```
wget -qO- http://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/akismet.2.5.3.zip | busybox unzip -
```

The dash after `unzip` is to use stdin as input.

You can even,

```
cat file.zip | busybox unzip -
```

But that's just redundant of `unzip file.zip`.

If your distro uses BusyBox by default (e.g. Alpine), just run `unzip -`.

BusyBox is [available](https://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-grep.cgi?grep=busybox&arch=x86_64) in Cygwin.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Eir Nym comment I tried `bsdtar` from `bsdtar` package on `Linux` (`Ubuntu`) and it works.

Answer (score 0):

(improved for Windows) IF you have Java JDK (big if!)

```
 get_zip_content | jar x
 # xv to list while extracting
 # optionally specify entries to extract; default is all
 # supply full /path_to_jdk/bin/jar if it's not in PATH
```

I rate this about 7/10 on the kludge scale.

Comment: Note: `jar` ignores permissions stored in the zip file. Executables are extracted as standard files (without the `x` persmission).